# Reading text directly into stack in DOS

Tags: assembly, x86, dos, 16-bit, tasm

I'm learning assembler (TASM on 16 bit DOS) and try to use 0Ah DOS service to read text directly into stack. It works pretty well in emu8086, while when I run it with actual TASM - it does not give any user input (no input at all, seems like skipping `INT 21h` at all).

Here's how I'm using it:

```
PROC _readNum USES BP AX BX CX DX SI
    PUSH BP
    MOV BP, SP
    SUB SP, 7

    MOV AH, 0Ah ;Buffered input
    MOV [BP-7], 5 ;Max number of characters to read (4 + 1 for enter)
    LEA DX, [BP-7]
    INT 21h ;This interrupt seems to be doing nothing at all
    ...
```

What can be the problem? Am I referencing the stack in wrong way? Thanks in advance.

Here's full code just in case:

```
ascii_offset EQU 30h
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
    ; add your data here!
    outStrA DB "Input A: $"
    outStrB DB "Input B: $"
    resultStr DB "Result of $"
    plusStr DB "+$"
    equalsStr DB " is $"
    eol DB 13, 10, "$"

    cnt DB 10
    rcnt DB 0
    buf DB 11 dup("$")

PRINT MACRO op1
    MOV AH, 09h
    LEA DX, op1
    INT 21h
ENDM

PRINTLN MACRO op1
    PRINT op1   
    PRINT eol
ENDM

PRINTEOL MACRO
    PRINT eol
ENDM

.code

PROC _printNum USES BP AX BX DX SI
    PUSH BP
    MOV BP, SP
    SUB SP, 6 ;Max number to print is 5 + $ sign    

    MOV AX, [BP+2]
    MOV DX, 0h ;Is required to divide a double pair
    MOV BH, 0h
    MOV BL, 10 ;Divisor

    LEA SI, [BP-1] ;Our string stored in memory (from end)
    MOV byte ptr [SI], "$" ;End of str
    _printNum_loop:
    DIV BX ;Result is in AX:DX
    ADD DL, ascii_offset ;Convert to ASCII
    DEC SI
    MOV [SI], DL    
    MOV DX, 0h ;Reset DX to divide again
    CMP AX, 0h ;If AX is 0
    JNE _printNum_loop

    PRINT [SI]

    MOV SP, BP
    POP BP
    RET 2
ENDP

PROC _readNum USES BP AX BX CX DX SI
    PUSH BP
    MOV BP, SP
    SUB SP, 7

    MOV AH, 0Ah ;Output to screen
    MOV [BP-7], 5 ;Max number of characters to read (4 + 1 for enter)
    LEA DX, [BP-7]
    INT 21h 

    MOV AX, 0h  ;Result
    MOV BX, 0h  ;Temporary result
    MOV CX, 0h  ;Loop counter   
    MOV CL, [BP-6] ;Loop counter
    LEA SI, [BP-5] ;Starting position to read number
    _readNum_strloop:
        MOV DX, 10 ; ;Will multiply AX by DX
        MUL DX ; AX = AX * DX
        MOV BL, [SI]        
        SUB BL, 30h
        ADD AX, BX
        INC SI  
    LOOP _readNum_strloop

    MOV SP, BP
    POP BP
    RET 0
ENDP

start:
; set segment registers:
    MOV AX, @data
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX

    PUSH 0ABCDh
    JMP _printNum

    MOV AX, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    INT 21h    

END start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `BP` to use the stack, instead, you should be using `SP`. `BP` is just for restoring the previous stack frame, not for using yours. THe entire point is that `BP` is unused until the end of the proc, but SP is used for stack access.

Comment: @Linuxios In 16-bit assembly you cannot use `sp` for addressing, you need to use eg. `bp`. In a standalone assembly executable you can use all registers the way you wish (within the limits set by processor architecture). In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes) there's a useful summary of all possible addressing modes for x86 processors.

Comment: @nrz: Really? Now that's odd. Sorry, I did a bit of 16 bit asm. but mostly 32 and 64. My bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on Alexey Frunze's answer:

Your code specifies a SMALL model. This directive tells the assembler to assume, among other things, that `DS = SS`, but it doesn't (can't) enforce it.

When DOS loads an EXE, it sets SS:SP to a location found in the file header. It sets DS to the beginning of the [PSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix) so you can get at command-line arguments and so forth.

The DOS buffered read function expects the buffer to be at DS:DX. You've properly loaded DX with BP-7 (the start of the buffer), but you also need to set DS ← SP before making the function call. You can do that with

```
MOV AX,SS
MOV DS,AX
```

or

```
PUSH SS
POP DS
```

There is no MOV DS,SS instruction.

Answer (score 2):

There might be a few bugs. Are you able to compile this?

```
PROC _printNum USES BP AX BX DX SI
    PUSH BP
    MOV BP, SP
    SUB SP, 6  ; Max number to print is 5 + $ sign
```

Here you modify `sp` even if you don't use `sp` for addressing or a as source before `mov sp,bp` in the end of this procedure, so this instruction is unnecessary.

```
    MOV AX, [BP+2]
```

This is not bug, just wondering... `ax` should now be `0xABCD`, is this correct?

```
    MOV DX, 0h  ; Is required to divide a double pair
    MOV BH, 0h
    MOV BL, 10  ; Divisor

    LEA SI, [BP-1]          ; Our string stored in memory (from end)
    MOV byte ptr [SI], "$"  ; End of str

_printNum_loop:
    DIV BX                  ; Result is in AX:DX
```

The result after `div bx` is not in `ax:dx`. In `ax` you will have the quotient and in `dx` you will have the remainder.

Then here:

```
PROC _readNum USES BP AX BX CX DX SI
    PUSH BP
    MOV BP, SP
    SUB SP, 7
```

Why this `sub sp,7`? First, you should keep `sp` aligned to 2, and second, why you modify `sp` here if you don't use it for addressing or as source before `mov sp,bp` in the end of this procedure?

```
MOV AH, 0Ah    ; Output to screen
MOV [BP-7], 5  ; Max number of characters to read (4 + 1 for enter)
```

Here you should define the size of the operand, eg. `mov byte [bp-7],5` or `mov word [bp-7],5`. Or with `ptr`, if TASM requires it, I don't know: `mov byte ptr [bp-7],5` or `mov word ptr [bp-7],5`.

```
LEA DX, [BP-7]
INT 21h
```

This does not make sense. According to [DOS INT 21h - DOS Function Codes documentation](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah0a) `mov ah, 0x0a; int 21` is buffered input, and `ds:dx` should to point to the input buffer. Probably your comment "Output to screen" is incorrect?

```
MOV AX, 0h     ; Result
MOV BX, 0h     ; Temporary result
MOV CX, 0h     ; Loop counter   
MOV CL, [BP-6] ; Loop counter
LEA SI, [BP-5] ; Starting position to read number
_readNum_strloop:
    MOV DX, 10 ; Will multiply AX by DX
    MUL DX ; AX = AX * DX
    MOV BL, [SI]        
    SUB BL, 30h
    ADD AX, BX
    INC SI  
LOOP _readNum_strloop
```

I think in this loop you have a risk of overflow. The biggest number that fits in any 16-bit register such as `ax` is 2^16-1 == 65535.

Comment: Thanks for detailed response. 1) As about `SUB SP,7`, AFAIK SP is used for PUSH/POP calls, so I added it in case I'd need to use those instructions in the function. If I don't - I'll remove that part. 2) As about AX, yes, it will have the 0ABCDh in it. 3) `ax:dx` part is just a bad comment, I commented there to remember that both registers will be changed in case I forget. 4) The comment is wrong, I fixed it in upper chunk of code, but forgot to fix the source code. Thanks again for your remarks, I'll try to fix all the points.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't go over all the code, but one problem is that your data and stack segments are different, that is, the program starts out with `ds`!=`ss`.

Therefore `LEA DX, [BP-7]` isn't going to provide the DOS input function with the correct address, because it's expected it in `ds:dx` and yet your buffer is at `ss:dx` and `ds`!=`ss`. The following `int 21h` call can then overwrite some memory and cause a hang or a crash.

You need to use proper addresses.

**UPDATE**: Some details.

Here's a slightly modified version of your program (the code in the question did not assemble well for me with TASM 3.2):

**UPDATE2**: Forgot to mention that all the changed lines contain comments starting with `;;;;`.

```
ascii_offset EQU 30h
.model small, C ;;;; added ", C"
.stack 100h
.data
    ; add your data here!
    outStrA DB "Input A: $"
    outStrB DB "Input B: $"
    resultStr DB "Result of $"
    plusStr DB "+$"
    equalsStr DB " is $"
    eol DB 13, 10, "$"

    cnt DB 10
    rcnt DB 0
    buf DB 11 dup("$")

PRINT MACRO op1
    MOV AH, 09h
    LEA DX, op1
    INT 21h
ENDM

PRINTLN MACRO op1
    PRINT op1   
    PRINT eol
ENDM

PRINTEOL MACRO
    PRINT eol
ENDM

.code

_printNum PROC USES BP AX BX DX SI ;;;; reordered PROC and _printNum
    PUSH BP
    MOV BP, SP
    SUB SP, 6 ;Max number to print is 5 + $ sign    

    MOV AX, [BP+2]
    MOV DX, 0h ;Is required to divide a double pair
    MOV BH, 0h
    MOV BL, 10 ;Divisor

    LEA SI, [BP-1] ;Our string stored in memory (from end)
    MOV byte ptr [SI], "$" ;End of str
    _printNum_loop:
    DIV BX ;Result is in AX:DX
    ADD DL, ascii_offset ;Convert to ASCII
    DEC SI
    MOV [SI], DL    
    MOV DX, 0h ;Reset DX to divide again
    CMP AX, 0h ;If AX is 0
    JNE _printNum_loop

    PRINT [SI]

    MOV SP, BP
    POP BP
    RET 2
ENDP

_readNum PROC USES BP AX BX CX DX SI ;;;; reordered PROC and _readNum
    PUSH BP
    MOV BP, SP
    SUB SP, 7

    MOV AH, 0Ah ;Output to screen
    MOV byte ptr [BP-7], 5 ;Max number of characters to read (4 + 1 for enter) ;;;; added "byte ptr"
    LEA DX, [BP-7]
    INT 21h 

    MOV AX, 0h  ;Result
    MOV BX, 0h  ;Temporary result
    MOV CX, 0h  ;Loop counter   
    MOV CL, [BP-6] ;Loop counter
    LEA SI, [BP-5] ;Starting position to read number
    _readNum_strloop:
        MOV DX, 10 ; ;Will multiply AX by DX
        MUL DX ; AX = AX * DX
        MOV BL, [SI]        
        SUB BL, 30h
        ADD AX, BX
        INC SI  
    LOOP _readNum_strloop

    MOV SP, BP
    POP BP
    RET 0
ENDP

start:
; set segment registers:
    MOV AX, @data
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV ES, AX

    PUSH 0ABCDh
    JMP _printNum

    MOV AX, 4c00h ; exit to operating system.
    INT 21h    

END start ; set entry point and stop the assembler.
```

Assembled (with TASM 3.2) as `tasm stkkbinp.asm` without errors or warnings.

Linked (with TLINK 3.01) as `tlink /m /s stkkbinp` without errors or warnings.

The map file produced by the linker is:

```
 Start  Stop   Length Name               Class

 00000H 00088H 00089H _TEXT              CODE
 00090H 000C5H 00036H _DATA              DATA
 000D0H 001CFH 00100H STACK              STACK


Detailed map of segments

 0000:0000 0089 C=CODE   S=_TEXT          G=(none)  M=STKKBINP.ASM ACBP=48
 0009:0000 0036 C=DATA   S=_DATA          G=DGROUP  M=STKKBINP.ASM ACBP=48
 0009:0040 0100 C=STACK  S=STACK          G=DGROUP  M=STKKBINP.ASM ACBP=74

  Address         Publics by Name


  Address         Publics by Value


Program entry point at 0000:0070
```

Now opening the program in TD and executing first 3 instructions:

[image]

You can clearly see on the screen that `ds` isn't equal `ss`. They are 4 apart, first going `.data` segment at 0x4caf, then going `.stack` at 0x4cb3. This difference of 4 in terms of segment values is equivalent to 4*0x10=0x40 bytes.

If you look at the map file above, you will see that, indeed, that's the distance between these segments:

```
 0009:0000 0036 C=DATA   S=_DATA          G=DGROUP  M=STKKBINP.ASM ACBP=48
 0009:0040 0100 C=STACK  S=STACK          G=DGROUP  M=STKKBINP.ASM ACBP=74
```

I cannot explain why the map file shows the same segment for both (9), but the linked executable has them different. But that's why the input won't work properly.

Comment: Thanks a lot for information. I was using older version of TASM - 2.0 , probably the reason it compiled well here.